# Do we need to use different DFP unit id's for android and ios

Tags: android, ios, blackberry, admob, google-dfp

Do we need to use different DFP unit id's for android and ios when we use Admob sdk?
Can we use DFP in blackberry for showing ads? I have used DFP in sencha project so the id used in that project will work for iphone and android do we need any changes?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/fundamentals

Comment: Hi anil, i have tried to build the sample project provided in that link and it was working for sample id, bu when i use live id the ad was not showing. Do you know why this happening?

Comment: please you create your id or App details in Admob account.@Linson

Comment: you get right id from Admob account.

Comment: I have already created an id and it is used in SenchaTouch project and that was working well. In that project used scripts to show the ad. In the case of native project we are getting a view object. So i cant figure out whats happening behind.

Comment: what problem your app?

Comment: your create different different id for android,ios etc...

Comment: i downloaded the sample project and the sample ad was showing, but when i tried to show the ad id which is used in other project didnt work. It logs like this onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.).

Comment: I didn't create different id's, just used the same id for both.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32680/discussion-between-anilmetatagg-and-linson)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need of different ad unit id's for android and ios. The problem i faced was the ad is not showing in India. Geotargeting must be set for an ad, while creating. So when you request for an ad from a location which set for the ad, it will display.